Why does MegaRAID show disk as suddenly become "unconfigured bad?"
I have LSI MegaRAID 9361-4i with 6 hard drives in RAID10.
While inserting another hard drive, the controller decided that 5 out of 6 disks are "unconfigured bad" and made my array offline.
Right click on "bad" drives had option "make unconfigured", so I marked all "bad" drives as "unconfigured good". Then the only option I got on these drives was "add missing drive" (or something similar I don't recall exactly what it says, but it led me to believe it will add the drive back to the array). So, it asked me which pair group and which index each drive should go to (I'm 99% sure I placed them back in correct positions), after that it restored the array and everything seemed to be good, except the system shows the drive as unformatted...
Later I read that I should have right click on the controller itself and select "scan foreign configuration"...
Anyway, did I just destroy my data or is there a way restore it somehow?
The array was encrypted with BitLocker, now it shows as unencrypted. I've spent 3 days trying different partition recovery tools none could find anything.

“did I just destroy my data” - Yes; The fact the drive is no longer encrypted suggests the necessary header to decrypt your data is gone

That didn't happen "suddenly". You messed it up.
And if there's no backup, the data is lost for sure.
